# Why does rust need lifetime annotations when the parameters of a function are references of two different types?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I am new to rust and I am trying understand/learn the borrow checker and lifetime annotations.

Why can the lifetime be inferred when a function accepts a single reference as a parameter?

```
fn main() {
    let num = 1;
    let num_ref = test(&num);
    println!("{}", num_ref);
}

fn test(num: &i32) -> &i32 {
    num
}
```

But not when the function has 2 parameters of different reference types?

```
fn main() {
    let num = 1;
    let s = "test";
    let num_ref = test(&num, s);
    println!("{}", num_ref);
}

fn test(num: &i32, s: &str) -> &i32 {
    num
}
```

Shouldn't the borrow checker be able to infer that the lifetime of the return should be the same as the &i32 reference? Since it is the only parameter that can be returned in this function? Or maybe am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or maybe am I missing something?

Yes. Rust doesn't do *lifetime inference*, instead it has a much simpler [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html) process, which has only a few simple cases, and thus has a very low cost/benefit ratio, and few pitfalls. However it does stumble very early as you've noticed.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, maybe I found out why. There could be cases like this I suppose

```
struct NumberContainer {
    x: i32
}

fn main() {
    let num = 1;
    let container = NumberContainer { x: 4 };
    let num_ref = test(&num, &container);
    println!("{}", num_ref);
}

fn test<'a>(num: &'a i32, container: &'a NumberContainer) -> &'a i32 {
    &container.x
}
```

The second type could be an object that contains an i32. So in this case, there could be potential for more than one possible &i32 reference return